# Solution for ms access invalid IDA error 7879

Tags: ms-access, ida

I've made an Access database with a connection to a DWH table. A form with 3 drop-down boxes is made for the user to select the correct value. But the first time a drop-down value is selected the user receives an error (in Dutch). 'An invalid IDA has been passed to Microsoft Access error handling. Please report this error and the steps that caused it.'

After clicking 'Ok' the error doesn't show up when selecting a value form the second drop-down box (and the third) in the same form. Only when the user selects this form again the error pops up when selecting the first drop-down value.

The only VBA code linked to this form is:

```
Option Compare Database

Private Sub Form_Load()

Me.AantalVanCONTRACT_NUMBER.ColumnWidth = 1.556 * 1440

End Sub
```

The strange thing is that the form works fine because the selected value gets inputted in the DWH table, but getting this error every time is pretty annoying.

Comment: And what happens if you don't have that code? There is no code associated with combobox?

Comment: Review https://www.errorvault.com/en/troubleshooting/runtime-errors/microsoft/microsoft-access/error-7879_an-invalid-ida-has-been-passed-to-microsoft-office-access-error-handling

Comment: Removing this peace of code seems to work. But it is still unclear why this small peace of coding causes this error. But the sub form also seems to work fine without this code, so removing it is a good solution. Thanks